# How to convert the perl code to python using map and lambda function

Tags: python

I have code in perl as mentioned below:

`%details_hash = map { $_ => $_ }  split(/\s+/, $details_data);`

It takes a string, splits it on basis of space and creates a hash having same key and value.
I need to rewrite the same code in python and create a dictionary.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This platform is no service for code translation. But if you present a problem, maybe someone is willing to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Hello world!'

print dict( (k,k) for k in s.split() )
```

Output:

```
{'world!': 'world!', 'Hello': 'Hello'}
```